# Match beginning of string with lookbehind and named group

Tags: regex-lookarounds

help needed to match full message in a Lookbehind.

Lets say i have the following simplified string:

```
1 hostname Here is some Text
```

at the beginning i could have 1 or 2 digits followed by space, which i would ignore.
then i need the first word captured as "host" 
and then i would like to look behind to the first space, so that capture group "message" has everything starting after the first 2 digits and space. i.e. "hostname Here is some Text"

my regex is:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}\s(?<host>[\w][\w\d\.@-]*)\s(?<message>(?<=\s).*$)
```

this gives me:

host = "hostname"
message = "Here is some Text"

I can't figure out how my lookbehind needs to look like.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found it. What needs to be done is to put message as the first group, and everything else, including the other groups inside the message group:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}\s(?<message>(?<host>[\w][\w\d\.@-]*)\s.*$)
```